# get who likes facebook post by php code

Tags: php, html, facebook

i want to get who like facebook post then and store it in php variable ... then look for specific name i want

if it is about facebook photo i can use this

```
$url = 'graph.facebook.com/photoid'
```

and then i use the code

```
file_get_contents($url);
```

and then search about the name who liked the photo

but in post there is no graph to get who like post 
i tried to put the whole link like

$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/AmrKhaled/posts/10152183719946165'

and then i use the code

```
file_get_contents($url);
```

but not found the name ... and if i var_dump($filegetcontent) and search my self no name is found

i need to know who like my post by php code ?? thanks

Comment: Do you have the right permissions?

Comment: what is the righ permission?? .. i think post is public or something else ??

Comment: Don’t use `file_get_contents` – use the PHP SDK instead and make regular API calls. In Graph API Explorer the likes on the post you mentioned show up fine, so it’s not likely a permission issue (but rather Facebook not liking your request made using `file_get_contents`, I’d say). https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=10152183719946165

Comment: the problem is about user agent .. so how can i put my user agent to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the user agent because you shouldn't be scraping the page.

The id in that post is at the end

`http://graph.facebook.com/10152183719946165`

You just need a valid access token to retrieve it.

> To read a Page you need:
>
> - an app or user access token for public and non-demographically restricted pages
> - a user access_token for restricted pages that the current user is able to view (no special permissions required)